# Pagination label for all rows

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I have a pagination as below:-
[image]

Now right now it has options 10,25,50 and I added one more for all rows as I have total of 1000 rows which I want to see without going to multiple pages 20 times. So i included data.length which gives me output as below now:-
[image]

My code is:-

```html
            <select value={pageSize} onChange={e => setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))}>
              {[10, 25, 50, data.length].map(pageSize =>(
                <option key ={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                  Show {pageSize}
                </option>
              ))}
```

I need to choose a label for data.length and not a number as shown in screenshot above. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write condition, if `data.length` equal `pageSize` you show text `All` else `pageSize`.

Example:

```
{[10, 25, 50, data.length].map((pageSize) => (
          <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
            Show {data.length === pageSize ? "All" : pageSize}
          </option>
        ))}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-shamir-veryj)

Comment: Got it thanks so much!!